# Mostrar texto digitado num campo de texto após clique em botão

Tags: java, swing

O código abaixo eu peguei da internet está funcionado pra mim.
No `main`, ele executa um form com o nome pra digitar e o botão `ok`.

Eu queria executar, no `main`, logo após o 
`new MeuPrograma();`
um `System.out.println("##")` onde exibisse o nome que o cara digitou lá no campo do `swing`
Como faço isso?

```
public class MeuPrograma extends JFrame  {



public static JTextField text = new JTextField(10);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel labelNome;
    private JTextField textFieldNome;
    private JButton buttonOk;

    public MeuPrograma() {
        setTitle("Programa Swing1");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        labelNome = new JLabel("Nome: ");
        textFieldNome = new JTextField(15);
        buttonOk = new JButton("OK");
        // --> adiciona os componentes a janela
        add(labelNome);
        add(textFieldNome);
        add(buttonOk);
        // --> ajusta o tamanho, a posicao e a acao ao fechar
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // --> mostra a janela
        setVisible(true);
    }



public static void main(String[] args)  {

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // --> cria um novo objeto do tipo Swing1
    // por causa da execucao multithreading da
    // API swing,isso deve ser feito dessa forma:
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MeuPrograma();
        }
    });
```

Comment: eu quero exibir o system.out.println depois q o cara clicar no ok

Comment: Se é desktop, o System.out.println não vai exibir nada, porque só exibe no console, a não ser que o usuário inicie a aplicação via linha de comando. Explique melhor onde você quer exibir e pra que.

Comment: na verdade eu tenho um código que gera um pdf usando o itext, quero pegar esse valor digitado e jogar pra dentro de uma variavel.. so o q quero saber é como pegar o valor que foi digitado quando o cara clicar no ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para capturar o valor digitado em uma `JTextFiled` após o botão for pressionado, adicione um [listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) no `JButton`, através do método [`actionPerformed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed-java.awt.event.ActionEvent-), algo assim:

```
buttonOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  String strTexto = textFieldNome.getText();
  //adicione o que quer fazer com o texto
 }
});
```

Por se tratar de uma invocação de [classe anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192104/28595), para passar o valor ao *listener* do `JButton`, você pode ou criar método externo que faça essa captura, e chamá-lo dentro da *action*, transformar `strTexto` em um parâmetro da classe `MeuPrograma` ou torná-la `final`.

Exemplo:

```
private String strTexto;

...

buttonOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  strTexto = textFieldNome.getText();

 }
});

...
```

Maiores esclarecimentos podem ser obtidos na [documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/).

**Referências para leitura:**

[How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

[How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)